# Loading files from disk to NSMutableArray removes NSMutableArray from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I'm loading a file to a `NSMutableArray`. I'm doing it like this:

```
if(!self.dataArray){
    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];
    self.dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayPath];
}
```

The array that is loaded into the file consists of multiple `NSDictionaries`.

However, this somehow deallocates the array in the memory because when I log `dataArray` after doing this, it logs `nil`. How come?

**Update**

I've figured out that `[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:arrayPath]` is logging nil because the code in which I'm uploading the content to the file, doesn't create the file:

```
// write data to disk
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,                                                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *arrayPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"array.out"];
 [self.dataArray writeToFile:arrayPath atomically:YES];

 NSLog(@"uploaded file: %@", arrayPath); // logs an arrayPath, but one that doesn't exists.
```

Comment: Are you using 'strong' property specifier for your dataArray?

Comment: arrayWithContentsOfFile -> "Returns nil if the file can’t be opened or if the contents of the file can’t be parsed into an array."

Comment: Not that this is the problem but please remove the needless line `self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`.

Comment: Yes, why are you creating an NSMutableArray and then throwing it away 3 lines later??

Comment: It's relatively certain that the `arrayWithContentsOfFile` operation is returning nil, either because the file doesn't exist, or because it's not a valid array image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Apple documentation, the array returns nil if the file can’t be opened or if the contents of the file can’t be parsed into an array.

Did you use the [writeToFile:atomically:] method to write the array to a file?

Also, make sure that the filePath string matches exactly on both write and read ends. I've wasted a lot of time trying to hunt down a bug when it turned out I had misspelled the name of the file or used the wrong file extension.

Another possibility: have you confirmed that this code is being executed? Sometimes I've had to change (!self.someProperty) to (self.someProperty != nil) in my if condition to get code like this to run.

Comment: BTW I would have posted that as a comment, but I'm new so I don't have that privilege yet. I didn't mean to imply that this was the answer per se.

Comment: Allright that could be it! How do I check if the file isn't nil?

Comment: Ok try this: get rid of the if condition. Instead, set self.dataArray = nil. Then check to make sure it's set to nil by using assert(self.dataArray == nil). Then run your code without conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following,

1. Check the **dataArray** is a **weak** property ? If so, change to **strong**.
2. Check the file exists at path, using

   **[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:arrayPath];**
3. Verify the file have expected content, by logging it.
4. Confirm the File content is organized as a property list (plist). Verify it in plist editor/Xcode.
5. If you dynamically creating it, check the path you are writing to.
6. Confirm the method of writing **NSArray** to plist. Use

   **[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];**

**Note:**

If you are dynamically creating the file and you are testing on Simulator; you can 
find the file by logging file path and following it on Finder.

**Property List Reference**

1. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)

Comment: Can you eloborate on point 4? I don't think creating a file on the simulator will show up in Xcode.

Comment: You can open it in Xcode. Just log the file path, copy it, then in Finder->Go to Folder, paste the path and Go. Open it.

Comment: Thanks :) I've updated the question and narrowed it down to the exact line that's causing the bug.

Comment: So, now you fixed it, ryt ?

Answer (score 0):

Peter Segerblom and wildBillMunson are right: the array returns nil if the file can't be opened or if its content can't be parsed into an array.

You said "array.out" is an array of NSDictionaries. Whenever I have that set of data, I use the plist type of file and read it this way:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:fullPath];
NSArray *data = (NSArray *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

Be sure to check if `fullPath` is not returning nil.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this didn't help :( it might work when there's some data in the data.plist already, but I append data only after it's nil in the viewdidload since the data is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Isn't there any data in your "array.out" file? If there isn't, how could arrayWithContentOfFile return any value other than nil? May be you should explain a little bit more about the process you're doing. That "asynchronously" thing is interesting and may have something to do with all this.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. Does this explain the problem a bit better?

Comment: Does "self.dataArray" contents are all property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray o NSDictionary)? Otherwise you won't be able to initialize a new array with that file. I ask you something because may be you cut out the code you're sharing here: are you saving the file in subdirectory within "directory"? If so, remember you have to create the subfolder first. Another thing: try changing the extension "out" for "plist".